# Advantages of InjectMocks for ClassUnderTest

Tags: unit-testing, mockito

I am writing unit test for my service (`ClassUnderTest`) class. I am using `@Mock` for all the data members.

Now, to test the `ClassUnderTest`, I need to create an object for the `ClassUnderTest`.

I have two options,
Create a new object for `ClassUnderTest` and send the mocks in the constructor.

Or use the `@InjectMocks` annotation for the `ClassUnderTest`.

I was wondering, are the two approaches same or are their some attentional benefits of using `@InjectMocks`?

```
@Mock
private NodeLaunchWorkflowService nodeLaunchWorkflowService;

@InjectMocks
private NodeLaunchWorkflowController nodeLaunchWorkflowController;
```

or

```
@Mock
private NodeLaunchWorkflowService nodeLaunchWorkflowService;

private NodeLaunchWorkflowController nodeLaunchWorkflowController; 
@Before
public void setUp() throws JSONException {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    nodeLaunchWorkflowController = new NodeLaunchWorkflowController(nodeLaunchWorkflowService)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite the opposite: There is some clear advantage to using the constructor pattern rather than `@InjectMocks`. In particular, as the [@InjectMocks documentation](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.4.1/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html) and [other articles](https://tedvinke.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/mockito-why-you-should-not-use-injectmocks-annotation-to-autowire-fields/), there are a wide variety of reasons that Mockito will silently fail to inject mocks. This means that innocent-looking class changes may cause obscure failures in your test, as opposed to the clear compilation failures that a constructor call would cause.

With certain automated refactoring tools, you may even be able to change your class in ways that your test will change correctly and automatically as well; it won't with @InjectMocks, which makes the constructor call reflectively deep within Mockito.

@InjectMocks may be useful for very quick unit test coverage in legacy code, but in new development it's usually much better to structure your components to be easily-testable (with exposed constructor calls, for instance) and then to test them with clear calls.